# How to use any keyword for protocols to conform with Equatable?

Tags: swift

I want to make my protocol conform to Equatable. However, whenever I use the protocol, I get an error `Type any {protocol} does not conform to Equatable.`

```
protocol ExampleDataProtocol: Equatable {
  var someData: Int { get set }
}

public extension ExampleDataProtocol {
  static func ==(lhs: any ExampleDataProtocol, rhs: any ExampleDataProtocol) -> Bool {
    return lhs.someData == rhs.someData
  }

  static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
    return lhs.someData == rhs.someData
  }
}

struct SomeStruct: Equatable { // Type 'SomeStruct' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'
  var someData: any ExampleDataProtocol
}
```

When I manually add protocol stubs, I am getting `any ExampleDataProtocol`  does not comfort to Equatable.

```
struct SomeStruct: Equatable {
  static func == (lhs: SomeStruct, rhs: SomeStruct) -> Bool {
    lhs.someData == rhs.someData // Type 'any ExampleDataProtocol' cannot conform to 'Equatable'
  }

  var someVar: any ExampleDataProtocol
}
```

Comment: Not sure about the fix, but I can shed some light on the issue. Even if `DataProtocol` conforms to `Equatable`, `any DataProtocol` does not (because `==` expects two instances of `Self`, but two instances of `any DataProtocol` can have two different concrete types). Providing an overload of `==` doesn't change that unfortunately (it would be like implementing a method `foo()` that's required by a protocol, but not actually declaring the `: Fooable` conformance)

Comment: Note that there is already a native Swift [DataProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dataprotocol)

Comment: ^ Ah, good callout. Intention of the naming was to make simple example. I did/do not intend to use DataProtocol as the real name. I will rename it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Protocols do not conform to protocols. They can require other protocols, but they do not conform to them. DataProtocol is not Equatable. It requires that conforming types be Equatable.

The existential `any DataProtocol` also does not conform to Equatable. Existentials never conform to protocols, but in this case Equatable requires that both of its parameters be of precisely the same type (Self), not "something conforming to this protocol." Your extension provides an `==` function, but it does not have the signature that [Equatable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable#) requires:

```
static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
```

Note the Self here. That is not the same thing as `any DataProtocol`. The extension attaches methods to conforming types. The existential (any) wraps a value that conforms to DataProtocol, but it does not *itself* conform to DataProtocol. (Some day I expect that `any` types may conform to some protocols, but they will probably never be able to conform to protocols with Self requirements or static methods, and Equatable has both.)

You can implement what you're describing this way:

```
extension DataProtocol {
    // This compares `self` to any other DataProtocol, not just Self.
    func isEqual(to other: some DataProtocol) -> Bool {
        return data == other.data
    }
}

struct SomeStruct {
    var someData: any DataProtocol
}

extension SomeStruct: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: SomeStruct, rhs: SomeStruct) -> Bool {
        lhs.someData.isEqual(to: rhs.someData)
    }
}
```